# How to convert a ArrayList of array of int to array of array of int in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have below code

```
List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();
result.add(new int[]{1,2});
result.add(new int[]{2,3});
int[][] re= result.toArray();
```

I tried to use toArray method to convert it to `int[][]` data format. But, it will throw error,"incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to int[][]".  Can someone explain the reason? and what I should do to convert it?

Comment: Why not just start with `new int[][]`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am doing some leetcode questions, so for this one, at first I don't know the size of the array. So I created a arraylist to add value dynamically. But the return needs int[][]

Comment: Most questions arent picky about data structures, only the final output... In which case, `List<List<Integer>>` would suit you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] re= result.toArray(new int[result.size()][]);
```

Comment: That's a single dimension array.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, thank you! Inspired by your comment, I checked the document again. I found out there is another api "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-"... so, I tried this ```int[][] re= result.toArray(new int[result.size()][]);``` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Because [`List.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) returns an `Object[]`. You want [`List.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) (which returns a generic `T[]`). Also, you can use `<>` (the diamond operator) with your `List`. Like,

```
List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
result.add(new int[] { 2, 3 });
int[][] re = result.toArray(new int[result.size()][]);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(re));
```

Outputs

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following will work for any size list of arrays.

```
int[][] re= result1.toArray(int[][]::new);  
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(re));
```

Prints

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Or three arrays

```
result1.add(new int[]{1,2,4});
result1.add(new int[]{2,3,5});
result1.add(new int[]{2,3,5});
int[][] re= result1.toArray(int[][]::new);  
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(re));
```

Prints

```
[[1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5]]
```